# bcp boost regex makefile configuration

Tags: regex, boost, makefile

I'm using bcp to scan my project and find all boost dependencies, and then to copy them into my boost folder.

For everything that only needs headers, this is fine, but for headers needing to build, I need to to build their library.

I'm using a Make to build and soon will be switching to a CMake for flexibility on the build process, and I want to include build regex along with the rest of my code.

How do I do this?

Here's my current makefile, it doesn't work like I thought it would:

```
MAKEFILE_NAME = ${firstword ${MAKEFILE_LIST}}
MKDIR_P = mkdir -p

INCLUDE = -Isrc -Isrc/lut -Isrc/state -Isrc/lut/boost
# MAIN = src/main.o
BOOST_CPP = $(wildcard src/lut/lib/*.cpp src/lut/lib/**/*.cpp)
BOOST_O = ${BOOST_CPP:.cpp=.o}
OBJECTS = src/lut/card_tree.o src/state/state.o src/state/card_library.o src/lut/field.o src/lut/field_tree.o src/lut/path_helper.o ${BOOST}
TEST_OBJECTS = tests/card_tree_tests.o tests/test_main.o tests/state_tests.o tests/field_tree_tests.o

DEPENDS = ${OBJECTS:.o=.d} ${TEST_OBJECTS:.o=.d} ${MAIN:.o=.d}

OUTDIR = bin
EXEC = munchkins.out
TEST_EXEC = munchkins.test

CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -g -Wall -DDEBUG -MMD -std=c++11 ${INCLUDE}



.PHONY : clean obj

${EXEC} : ${OBJECTS} ${TEST_OBJECTS}
    ${MKDIR_P} ${OUTDIR}
    ${CXX} ${CXXFALGS} $^ -o ${OUTDIR}/${TEST_EXEC}

${OBJECTS} : ${MAKEFILE_NAME}

obj : ${OBJECTS} ${MAIN}
        ${MKDIR_P} ${OUTDIR}
        ${CXX} ${CXXFLAGS} $^ -o ${OUTDIR}/$@

-include ${DEPENDS}

clean :
        rm -f ${DEPENDS} ${MAIN} ${OBJECTS} ${TEST_OBJECTS} ${OUTDIR}/${EXEC} ${OUTDIR}/${TEST_EXEC}
```

I was trying to get the boost .cpps at the top for the .o files, but this didn't work of course.

I get this error when I try to compile because it can't link:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::regex_error::regex_error(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, boost::regex_constants::error_type, long)", referenced from:
```

And then proceeds to list a bunch of undefined symbols relating to regex.

How can I include the regex lib in my build?

Comment: BCP... as in SQL Server's "bulk copy program"? I dont see where that fits into this question. Is this a mixup of tags?

Comment: Yeah, I meant BCP like the boost program to copy dependencies to a local project